# How to compile OpenCV statically linked with libstdc++

Tags: opencv, mingw

I need to compile OpenCV statically linked with libstdc++ to avoid problems of different dll versions of libstdc++-6.dll needed by Qt5 and OpenCV. Following the steps of this article: http://www.argong.com/docs/how-to-OpenCV-2.2.0.pdf and adding the lines below to CMakeLists.txt i expected to get the OpenCV DLLs statically linked with libstdc++, but the OpenCV continues dependent of the libstdc++-6.dll. What i'm doing wrong to get the OpenCV libraries statically linked with libstdc++?

```
  if (MINGW)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -static-libgcc")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS} -static-libgcc -s")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -s")
  endif()
```

Comment: Which version do You try to compile?

Comment: OpenCV 2.4.4 with CMake 2.8.10 and MinGW 4.7

Comment: I have a similar problem: I use the -static-libdstdc++ and yet the result includes the DLL anyway, so it feels like that -static command line option does not do what it is supposed to do. I also get the gcc DLL and the -static option by itself also has no effect... I checked with VERBOSE to make sure that it would appear on the linker's command line, and it does... what are we doing wrong?

Comment: mingw probably doesn't have that option working, i read in article the other day that either one of that options requires certain version of gcc (might have been something near 4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure you're not pulling dependencies on libraries that link on shared system libraries. You can for example enable compilation of bundled source components like zlib, jpeg, etc., with flags `BUILD_ZLIB`, `BUILD_JPEG`, etc. You can also disable dependencies on optional components like Vtk (`WITH_VTK` flag) and others that may be already present in the system as shared libraries. Then, if you are building OpenCV as a shared library, push the setting on the shared linker flags variable (`CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS`) in the cache with [`cmake -C`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake.1.html) command:

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
```

Alternatively, if you are compiling OpenCV statically with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=FALSE`, you can plug gcc linker flags for static linking on your final shared object or executable.